# deque implementation options

Tags: c++, deque

I need to build my own deque as the environment I program in has no such thing. I find my self torn between two choices as to how to implement it:

- I can manage a growable array of pointers to arrays which hold the data. The question is, how do I determine the size of each array secondary?
- I can have one large buffer that I periodically grow and essentially build a circular queue on top of it. This seems bad after a certain size as large allocations get harder to efficiently fulfill.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just implement a doubly linked list...

Comment: In C++, when one refers to a deque, it is reasonable to assume random access is desired in addition to the more general requirements, thanks to the naming scheme chosen by the original designers.

Answer (score 2):

For your first option, you could simply double the size of each array from the one before as you allocate them, perhaps up to some upper bound determined by something you know about your application or memory constraints.

The second you seem to have figured out.

Why not just a simple doubly-linked list? Do you need fast random access?

Comment: +1 on the exponential growth. IIRC most std containers do the same.

Comment: A doubly linked list wastes tons of memory on pointers. For my structure, using the circular buffer lets me store twice as many elements.

Comment: Then your first option is probably ideal. You don't incur any copy overhead (in memory and time) when trying to expand the list, and you can also easily shrink the list if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

One more way could be have lists of vectors( fixed size). Benefit of lists as first DS is you can add elements at head and tail and in between as well. The benefit of having fixed size vector is you can simulate two-dimention array with addition / deletion of row is constant time. Now suppose you want to add on head. You should add one node in list at head ( const time ), then add the entry at the last of the fixed size vector. So think of any entry at head when the dequeue is already having data, you are inserting at the last column of the first row. Any further insertion at head will happen at second last unfilled column of first row if there is space available in the row. other wise repeat the same step.
Normal insertions at the end will happen usually as end of the list's vector where insertions are happening from start of the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a combination of your two options- multiple smaller buffers and have each "end" point to the other, essentially becoming a larger circular array.  That way you shouldn't need to allocate buffers nearly as often.  As to the size of the secondary buffers, I think Collin's suggestion is a good one- increase the size as you go.